# Persistent Queue datastructure

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to make a class Persistent queue in which the function enqueue takes an element enqueues it to the current queue and return the new queue. How ever the original queue remains unchanged. Similarly the dequeue function removes the front element an returns the new queue but the original queue remains unchanged. This can of course be done in O(length of queue) but can i do it faster.??

Comment: Is there any reason why you need immutable queues?

Comment: @Gab Yes, because answering useless questions is useless. If we know what the asker intends to do one can suggest better ways of doing that than what the asker initially intended to do.

Comment: Just to go back to the topic: I believe that you won't be able to copy every element of any collection without iterating on each of them once. Thus, better than O(n) doesn't seem reasonable to me.

Comment: We got it as an think at home, but i just could not figure it

Comment: @ccjmne cant we enqueue return and and then remove it, i know execution stops after return but ne way to go around it

Comment: @AdityaNambiar I would avoid having to remove it at all, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a linked list as queue (not LinkedList, but your own implementation).

To add a new element you only have to create a new instance of your queue class, set its start element to the copied queue's start element, and create a new end element.

Removing an element is similar, but set the end element of the new queue to the second to last element of the copied queue.

The queue class could look like this:

```
static class Node {
    final Node next;
    final Object o;
    Node(Node next, Object o) {...}
}

final Node start, end;

private Queue(Node start, Node end) {...}

public Queue(Object o) {
    start = end = new Node(null, o);
}

public Queue add(Object o) {
    return new Queue(start, new Node(end, o));
}

public Queue remove() {
    return new Queue(start, end.next);
}
```

The complexity of this queue's `add` and `remove` methods is O(1).

Please note that you can only iterate this queue in reverse order (i.e. newest elements first). Maybe you can come up with something that can be iterated the other way around or even in both directions.

Comment: A doubly linked list should allow you to iterate in both directions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey But then you won't be able to add or remove in O(1), as you would have to copy every node (if my code is naively extended with a new `Node previous`)

Comment: Good point.  Every Queue would need to have a previous field of it's own. This would be less of a problem if you only have one producer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have a look to scala implementation. Comment at the top of the class describes the chosen approach (complexity : `O(1)`).

> `Queue` is implemented as a pair of `List`s, one containing the ''in'' elements and the other the ''out'' elements.
>     
> Elements are added to the ''in'' list and removed from the ''out'' list. When the ''out'' list runs dry, the
>    queue is pivoted by replacing the ''out'' list by ''in.reverse'', and ''in'' by ''Nil''.
>    
> Adding items to the queue always has cost `O(1)`. Removing items has cost `O(1)`, except in the case
>    where a pivot is required, in which case, a cost of `O(n)` is incurred, where `n` is the number of elements in the queue. When this happens,
>    `n` remove operations with `O(1)` cost are guaranteed. Removing an item is on average `O(1)`.

http://xuwei-k.github.io/scala-library-sxr/scala-library-2.10.0/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala.html

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use Java Chronicle (disclaimer: which I wrote).  This is an unbounded off heap persisted queue which is stored on disk or tmpfs (shared memory).

In this approach your consumer keeps track of where it is up to in the queue, but no entry is actually removed (except in a daily or weekly maintenance cycle)

This avoids the need to alter the queue except when adding to it, and you would not need to copy it.

As such maintaining multiple references to where each consumer believes is the tail of the queue is O(1) for each consumer.

As Chronicle uses a compact binary form, the limit to how much you can store is limited by your disk space. e.g. a 2 TB drive can store this much data even on a machine with 8 GB before you have to rotate the queue logs.

Comment: You cannot add elements without modifying the data structure with this approach

Comment: @Njol If you need this you can also record where the end is. To take a snap shot all you need to know is the start and the end. O(1).  The problem arises only if you want to add to multiple snapshots and you cannot apply any filters of the queued messages.